# webrtc: can TURN server be used as media server?

Tags: webrtc

Is it possible to use a TURN server to play the role of a media server to relay streams ? (like Janus or Kurento)

user1<----->turn<------>user2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TURN servers only help in 1to1 call as media(Encrypted) relayer through NAT. We can't decrypt the media at TURN server.

WebRTC [MediaServer/Gateways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC_Gateway) like Janus, will help in advanced use cases like streaming, conference, PSTN/SIP and recording.

Read the [tutorial](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/) and choose the media server based on your use cases

Comment: Since chrome can relay streams, is is possible to use chromium on server to relay streams like a sfu ?